# Setting ArcMap Data Source Refresh Interval?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-10.6, data-source, refresh

In ArcGIS Online there is an option to set a refresh data interval.

Is there a way to accomplish the same within ArcMap?

Specifically, my data source is inside an Enterprise GDB (Oracle).

I can pan the map around and that refreshes the data however I am looking for a way to not interact with the map and have it refresh on its own.

It seems this is possible in ArcGIS Pro 2.0+ but I haven't found a solution yet for ArcMap except for creating a simple python add-in which I would prefer to avoid because it halts other operations inside the ArcMap session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ArcGIS Ideas to have more options for refreshing ArcMap maps.

One that you may wish to add your vote to is [Auto Initiate the "Refresh Button" every 10, 20, or 30 minutes MXD Setting option](https://community.esri.com/ideas/7328).

However, with ArcMap now so late in its life cycle, and the functionality you seek appearing to already be present in ArcGIS Pro, I think a better way forward may be to investigate whether your workflow can be undertaken in ArcGIS Pro instead.